# Membership.ValidateUser works in 1 project fails in the other

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I have a simple CLI app to create/update/delete users of an SqlMembershipProvider.  It works, and I can validate just fine **from the CLI app**.

As soon as I try to do it from the related asp.net app, however, it fails.  I've literally copy/pasted the relevant web.conf/app.config sections, so I have no clue why it's failing.

```
<machineKey validationKey="C94FA3782AAF21E932CAA92DC2A0641951E3A76E50DD25B19C627BA01E259C6CBC7839A7803A59EF3BF855152369A6AB10CC259513BE7ACA4E842B962FD1D8A4"
                decryptionKey="2EA6D270AD94361ECFDCED5070D76FD67D9A147FEEBC8388FE9B73B450A04560"
                validation="SHA1"
                decryption="AES" />

    <membership defaultProvider="MembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="MembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
             connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" 
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
             enablePasswordReset="true" 
             requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
             requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
             minRequiredPasswordLength="1" 
             minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
             passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
             passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

This is in both the web.config and app.config, can someone explain why this will validate in the CLI project and not the asp.net project?

And to be clear, here is the code that isn't validationg

```
Membership.ValidateUser("fake", "fake") // actual test un/pwd combo
```

I've verified that the un/pwd is in fact correct.

Comment: I might be missing something obvious here, but what happens when it "fails" in the web app?  Do you get a specific error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing anything else about you applications, it seems that the most likely issue is the applicationName attribute in the membership/providers/add node in the config files. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.applicationname.aspx

These applications are probably defaulting to separate application names/identifiers. So when you attempt to login through the web app the provider only sees access granted to the CLI app. The CLI app may not have access to the web root or virtual path info (with no http context) to create a default name so it is probably defaulting to something different than your web app applicationName.

Look at this link for a good explanation: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/22/Always-set-the-_2200_applicationName_2200_-property-when-configuring-ASP.NET-2.0-Membership-and-other-Providers.aspx

You can handle this in two ways:

- Try setting the applicationName to the same string in both configurations.

OR

- Ensure that there are two entries for the user "fake" in the aspnet_Membership table. One for the CLI app and one for the Web app. You should find the applicationID for each application listed in the aspnet_Application table.

Here is another reference where someone used the SqlMembershipProvider outside of an asp.net app: http://mdrasel.wordpress.com/2011/02/01/asp-net-membership-provider-outside-of-web-application/. Note the use of the applicationName attribute.

Comment: yeah, I realized after I posted that I hadn't set the app name.  silly mistake.